# Google App Engine -- absolutely no MySQL administration skills required?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm yet to deploy an app to AWS or GAE thus such things aren't very clear to me. In the case of GAE which I'm considering, since they're a PaaS, and since they are saying that a developer's only concern will be at the application layer, does that mean that I have two and only two responsibilities -- one, making sure that my application code meets secure standards and, two, the very least I must do database-wise is that I make sure the table relationships are solid?

Are those two conclusions correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct - GAE is a PaaS so there will be no admin/maintenance required. You will just need to set [initial configuration for Cloud SQL and conform to API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/).

You will still need to maintain your SQL database though: create tables, set indexes, optimise queries, etc.. This is all application specific, so it has to be done by the developer.